# Is apache's IncludeOptional config evaluated at runtime?

Tags: apache, config

I'm trying to set up a web application such that by placing a symlink on disk the behavior of apache is altered. If I use the `IncludeOptional` configuration directive, will I still need to reload apache for the new symlink to take effect, or is it, like .htaccess files, checked at runtime and kept up to date with changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, the answer is yes. In order to re-evaluate the state of the filesystem based on the content of an IncludeOptional directive, apache will need to at least be gracefully reloaded.